# std::unordered_map non assignable internal pair. How?

Tags: c++, unordered-map, assignment-operator

If `*map_it` returns a `&` to a `std::pair`, how can this not work?
Visual Studio points me to `pair& operator=(const volatile pair&) = delete;`. How does this work and what sort of overloading magic is happening here?

Found it while trying to implement a Hash Table. I want the key to be constant and the value to be mutable, and the whole pair to not be assignable. Took a look at `Visual Studio`'s implementation and I still can't figure it out. I believe it must be a really simple rule that I still have no knowledge of.

Here's an example:

```
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> map;
    map[1] = 2;
    auto map_it = map.begin();
    auto & map_pair = *map_it;

    // How can they prevent this?
    map_pair = std::pair<int const, int>(1, 2);

    // And this one?
    std::pair<int const, int> p(1, 2);
    map_pair = p;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's literally disabled by this:

```
pair& operator=(const volatile pair&) = delete;
```

You can do this to methods. For example

```
class foo {
    public:
        foo(const foo &) = delete; // disallows copy construction
        foo &operator(foo const &) = delete; // disallows move construction
};
```

If you want to override a value and are using C++17, you can use std::unordered_map::insert_or_assign(). I *think* otherwise you can use a pair of (int, int *) mapping, and changing the value at the pointer instead of trying to change the value itself.

The term is a [deleted function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions), since C++11

> If, instead of a function body, the special syntax = delete ; is used, the function is defined as deleted. Any use of a deleted function is ill-formed (the program will not compile). This includes calls, both explicit (with a function call operator) and implicit (a call to deleted overloaded operator, special member function, allocation function etc)

Comment: I remembered now while searching that you can't assign to a const variable. `std::pair` is probably using some `snifae` trick to disable `operator=` if one of it's members happens to be const.

Comment: @JoãoPires The compiler itself can auto-delete an implicitly-generated assignment operator if not all members are assignable (amongst other reasons). In this case, the `first` member of the `std::pair` used for `std::(unordered_)map::value_type` is declared as `const Key` and thus not assignable, so the compiler can delete `operator=` for that `value_type` if the code is not deleting it explicitly (which, based on the OP's statement, is apparently being done).

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same issue...

auto & map_pair = *map_it;

The type of map_pair is

std::pair<const int, int>&

so, map_pair.first is not assignable!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34034147)